# functional analysis-normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Can somebody please help me to find the answer for this problem...

Let $V$ be a norm linear space and let $x\in V\setminus\{0\}$. Also let $W$ be a linear subspace of $V$. Show that if there is $r>0$ such that $\{y \in V \mid  \lVert y\rVert< r\}$ is a subset of $W$, then $\frac{rx}{2\lVert x\rVert}\in W$.

Comment: I have edited the question. However I am not sure what exactly was your question at the end. Please use LaTeX in the future and try and ask questions with a bit more clarity in your words.It'll help you get better answers.

Comment: Right, Davide got it clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_r=\{y\in V: ||y||<r\}$. Because $||x||\ne 0$, we get
$$
||\frac{r}{2||x||}x||=|\frac{r}{2||x||}|\cdot ||x||=\frac{r}{2||x||}\cdot ||x||=\frac{r}{2}<r.
$$
This implies that $\displaystyle{\frac{r}{2||x||}x}\in B_r$ and because $B_r\subseteq W$, the result follows. Thats what Davide means...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** what is the norm of $\frac r{2\lVert x\rVert}x$? What can we say about elements which have norm $<r$?

Comment: Sorry Davide,I didn't get your hint!can you please explain me further..

Comment: What don't you get exactly?